# How to tell if a POI is between two locations on the route with Skobbler maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

Im working on an app that shows different POIs in between location and destination on a route.

Together with a map, there is a list view representation of the route, with Location showing first (New York for example), Destination in the end (Let's say Boston) and POIs in between.

But if I add another location in between
, lets say Chicago, and then continue adding those POIs, is there any way to know if an added POI is on a route between New York and Chicago, or it is between Chicago and Boston?

So is there a way of telling if a coordinate is between two other coordinates, but not in the general space, but on that route exactly?

Or, is there a way of knowing how far is the POI from the starting point of the route?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK does not offer any helper functions for calculating this, but since you have access to the geometry of the route (via the get [routeCoordinatesForRouteWithId](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/Classes/SKRoutingService.html#//api/name/routeCoordinatesForRouteWithId:) method) you can calculate the distance from your point to the route.

There are a number of ways of doing this, described on multiple threads on Stackoverflow:

- [Find nearest point in polyline/path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023272/find-nearest-point-in-polyline-path/28028023#28028023)
- [Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment?lq=1)
- [Check user is following the route or not (iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584745/check-user-is-following-the-route-or-not-iphone)

**Note:** you can also try to add the POI as a viaPoint to the existing route - if the route already passes that point then the result will be the same route (geometry wise) - if not then a new route geometry will be generated.